# Wordpress visual editor not producing paragraph tags

Tags: wordpress

When my client is editing a page on visual editor, they select heading 1 and start typing.

If we switch to text editor is shows the text with the `<h1>` tags correctly.

This also works fine with `<a>` links

However if the client selects paragraph and we then check in the text editor it has not picked up at all. Its missing the `<p>` tags

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Because `<p>` tag is the most common and the default, it is not displayed when you switch the editor into Text Mode. If you save the page, display it in your browser (the frontend part visible by the visitors, not the backend) and check its source code (Ctrl + U), you should see the `<p></p>` correctly used.

In the text editor, a simple new line (\n) produces a `<br />` tag. When 2 new lines chars are typed, the current paragraph is closed `</p>` and a new one is opened `<p>`.

Comment: when i save there are still no <p> tags at all

Comment: Are the <p> tags displayed in page on the frontend side, visible by your visitors ( not in the backend part) ?

Comment: No thats the strange thing. If i go into the text and physically put a <p> tag then save. I can see on the visual editor its made it break a line like it should and then when i load up the actual page it has worked.

Its just not working through the visual

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue where the content from the visual editor was coming through to the front end but it wouldn't add in any paragraphs. After much searching I came across the solution in that TinyMCE was the cause. I added in the following code to my functions.php and it worked.

```
function ikreativ_tinymce_fix( $init )
{
    // html elements being stripped
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'div[*], article[*]';

    // don't remove line breaks
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false;

    // convert newline characters to BR
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true;

    // don't remove redundant BR
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;

    // pass back to wordpress
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'ikreativ_tinymce_fix');
```

The solution came from https://ikreativ.com/stop-wordpress-removing-html/ but it took me a while to find it so I thought I would repost in here for anyone else having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the method to add tags to the back-end WP text editor, but if you want to show content on a page with added p tags (for example, in a custom PHP-script), you can use in-built `wpautop()` function.